# Check whether any boolean column has value TRUE

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a table with a boolean column and want know if atleast one record has a `TRUE` value in that column.

This query works as expected with postgresql:

```sql
SELECT sum(coalesce(CAST(boolean_column AS INT),0)) <> 0
FROM entity
WHERE correlation_id = 123;
```

But in case of Microsoft SQL Server i get a syntax error near '<'!

Background is that my application should support both: PostgreSQL and SQL-Server and I don't want to create different SQL scripts for each database backend.

A work-around may be to use an INT column and handle the boolean expression at application level.

Any hints welcome!

Comment: SQL Server does not have syntax for arbitrary boolean expressions (in the `SELECT`). Use a `CASE` expression or an `IIF`.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: *I don't want to create different SQL scripts for each database backend* Unfortunately that's not how things work, if you want to have compatible SQL with two different platforms you need to account for their syntactical variances or language extensions. Just like every ORM has to do.

Comment: Why do you `CAST(boolean_column AS INT)`? What is the type of the column and is it nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query solved my problem for both: PostgreSQL and SQL-Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 1
FROM entity
WHERE correlation_id = 123
  AND CAST(boolean_column AS INT) = 1
```

Because in PostgreSQL the `boolean_column` is of type `BOOLEAN` and in SQL-Server it is of type `BIT`. PostgreSQL interprets `1` as `TRUE` and that is all I am interested in (see [PostgreSQL - Boolean Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using EXISTS which is supported by both PostgreSQL and SQL Server, and is generally more performant than a full count of matching rows. The query stops as soon as it finds a single matching row:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM entity WHERE boolean_column = TRUE AND correlation_id = 123);
```

SQL Server does not have a TRUE literal and uses 1 for BIT columns, which are typically used to represent boolean values.

In SQL Server, you can modify the query like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM entity WHERE boolean_column = 1 AND correlation_id = 123) 
   THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 
   END;
```

In PostgreSQL,

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM entity WHERE boolean_column = TRUE AND correlation_id = 123) 
   THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 
   END;
```

Comment: SQL-Server does not have TRUE and FALSE, only 1 and 0 for BIT columns that are usually used as Boolean columns.

Comment: Yes exactly. This code is compatible with PostgreSQL as well as SQL-Server as in SQL Server the boolean TRUE/FALSE is represented by 1/0 respectively while In PostgreSQL, you can use TRUE directly.

Comment: If you need to convert this into a number (1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE), you can do so using a CASE expression as mentioned in the second block of code

Comment: You cannot write `WHERE boolean_column = TRUE` in SQL-Server, because there is no `TRUE` literal! The `boolean_column` if converted correctly is a `BIT` column and you can compare with `WHERE boolean_column = 1`

Comment: My mistake. Apologies. I have updated the query for SQL server.